# CreatorName is null on Case Comments

Tags: apex, case

I have created two case comments on my case.But when I query for CreatorName in casecomments  ..it is showing as null.I think it should show the Created By name (creator name)of case comments.FYI : chatter answers is enabled in my org

```
Select c.Parent.Subject, c.ParentId, c.LastModifiedDate, c.Id, c.CreatorName, c.CommentBody From CaseComment c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for CaseComment object:

> Name of the user who posted the question or reply. Only the first name of internal users (agents) appears to portal users in the feed. Chatter Answers must be enabled to view this field. This field is available in API version 26.0 and later.

Do you have Chatter Answers enabled? If not, you might query CreatedBy.Name instead.

Comment: chatter answers in enabled